# SQL - count of number of times a foreign key appears in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Schema Info: [image: SCHEMA]

3 tables are concerned: SIGHTING, SPOTTER, AND ORG

SIGHTING references SPOTTER through FK SpotterId.

SPOTTER references ORG through FK OrgId.

I would like a query to return two columns; one for a list of ORG.OrgName, and another for the respective total count of Spotter_ID appearances in SIGHTINGS for the corresponding ORG.OrgID.

What I have done below returns the incorrect counts for each row returned:

```
SELECT ORG.ORG_NAME AS ORG_NAME,
       (SELECT COUNT(SIGHTINGS.SPOTTER_ID) 
          FROM SIGHTINGS
             , SPOTTERS 
         WHERE SIGHTINGS.SPOTTER_ID = SPOTTERS.SPOTTER_ID 
          AND SPOTTERS.ORG_ID=ORG.ORG_ID) AS ORG_COUNT 
  FROM ORG;
```

Comment: Please avoid posting images; you table structure could be better explained by posting the DDL statements. Also, please post some sample data and desired result

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you only need aggregation:

```
  SELECT COUNT(1), orgName
    FROM SIGHTING
         INNER JOIN SPOTTER USING (spotterId)
         INNER JOIN ORG USING (orgId)
GROUP BY orgName
```

Comment: Why `count(1)`? [Count(*) would be faster!](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156151916789#25335122556076) (search for "Finally - conclusive proof" if that link takes you to the top of the page)

Comment: This works perfectly. It's also much cleaner than  my posted answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Boneist - I may be mistaken, but doesn't the optimizer automatically - and super-quickly  - convert `count(1)` to `count(*)`, at least in the newer versions of Oracle? Perhaps that wasn't so 15 years ago when that article was written. Still no reason to write `count(1)`, but I heard that argument before and I don't find it very convincing (anymore, perhaps).

Comment: @mathguy it was a tongue-in-cheek comment - did you look at the link I posted? Unfortunately, I accidentally forgot to add a smiley to my earlier comment

Comment: @Boneist  - as Tom said:"ROTFL :) 
thanks (at first, i was reading this seriously.... ) ".. I'm in good company :)

Comment: @Aleksej it's still my favourite argument in favour of count(*)! *{;-)

Comment: @Boneist - lol, no, I followed the link, I saw it was to AskTom and the year, and that was all I looked at. But, seriously, I heard that argument (that count(*) is faster) from respected people, which always puzzled me. Cheers!

Comment: @mathguy no worries; count(1) irritates me in the same way it does Tom; its semantically meaningless, whereas count(*) actually means something! At least, IMHO! *{;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple aggregation, but you only need one `JOIN`:

```
select o.orgname, count(*) as numSpotters
from org o join
     spotters s
     on o.orgId = s.orgId
group by o.orgname;
```

Note:  If you want *all* organizations, even those with no spotters, then use `left join` instead of `join`.

Comment: The requirement was to count from the SIGHTINGS table (that is, to count sightings of spotters belonging to an organization) - not to count the spotters themselves. This is why two joins are needed.

Comment: @mathguy . . . Actually, the question is ambiguous:  "another for the respective total count of Spotter_ID".  I might take this to be the distinct count.

Comment: @user3603179 - please read the two comments to Gordon's answer (right above this one) - you need to clarify the assignment. Gordon is right, the way you worded it can be interpreted either way. If a spotter appears four times in the sightings table, does that count as "one" or as "four" in your requirement?

Comment: @mathguy Sorry for not being clear, but from your example, a spotter appearing 4 times will add 4 to the count.